# Implementing locking in a shared document editing environment.

Tags: java, web-applications, locking

I have implement a grid which displays document metadata and the user is able to edit the document on right click. I wanted to implement a locking mechanism for this. What would be the best way to put a lock on the document when one user has opened the editor ? These documents do reside in the database.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a column that specifies who currently has the file checked out.  When a person tries to check out a file, if that column is set, they will not be able to check it out, and will be notified of who has it checked out.  Unless you have thousands of requests per second for a single document, this method will work fine.

Comment: What happens when the user who had originally checked it out never saves or gracefully terminates his session? How and under what conditions are you going to unset this field so it becomes available to others?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding a column to say who has the file checked out and preventing access using that. You can add a timestamp for when the lock was requested.

This way, if someone requests it and the lock is, for example, 30 mins old with no changes made, they can take the lock. (If the original user didn't quit gracefully or something).

Answer (score 0):

If the documents are in a database, the database itself should have support for preventing inconsistent access.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setTransactionIsolation%28int%29

If the editor does not keep database transactions/connections open for the duration of file editing, however, and the java application runs client-side rather than server-side (as you could simply create a lock in the editor for concurrency on the server side), then things get a bit trickier and I haven't yet had enough database experience to say how you would resolve that, as using a field in the database to indicate editing status would have concurrency problems with that type of setup (unless the database itself supports locking on records, but that would depend on the DB engine in use).

Oh, one possibility would be to use file modification times (have a timestamp field in the database and update it each time a file is modified) and keep a no-dirty-reads-allowed transaction in use while checking the timestamp and determining if the file was modified by another user after the user attempting to save last accessed it; if so, it won't save the file to the database and will instead alert the user that the server-side file was changed and ask if they want to view the changes (similar to how version control systems work). By disallowing dirty reads for all such transactions, that should prevent other users from changing the file's record while the first transaction is open (to mark a record as "dirty", you could perhaps use a dummy field that would be updated at the start of each transaction with some random value). (Note: aglassman's answer would work similarly to this.)